Возможен ли смешанный вывод для std::print из разных потоков?
Например, в первом потоке мы делаем std::print("12");, а во втором - std::print("34");. Возможен ли какой-либо вывод кроме "1234"/"3412"? А для fmt::print и std::cout?

Это скорее вопрос реализации; стандарт не даст ни положительного, ни отрицательного ответа.

@AlexF можно ли это как-то просто порешать, не замедляя все выводы мьютексами?

Замедлить всё локфри логированием. Используйте библиотеку для логирования с поддержкой параллельного вывода. Или напишите её сами (простую). Это хорошее упражнение.

@StanislavVolodarskiy из доки не очень ясно, quill не будет смешивать?

Не будет: "Ordered Log Statements: Log statements are ordered by timestamp even when produced by different threads, facilitating easier debugging of multithreaded applications."
